# how to bind mvc4 radiobutton to a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello I've got a simple user class and in this user classs I've got property of type `List<Contact>`

```
public  class User
{
  public User()
  {
    this.AddressContact = new List<Contact>();
  }           
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public List<Contact> AddressContact { get; set; }                         
}

public class Contact
{
  public int Id { get;set; }
  public string NameCompany {get;set;}
  public string Street {get; set; }
  public string Town {get; set; }
  public string Telephone {get; set;}
  public string Fax {get; set;}
}
```

I've got an action which return a view model

```
public ActionResult ConfirmationOrder()
{
  ConfirmationModel confmodel = new ConfirmationModel();
  Cart cart = (Cart)Session["Cart"];
  User contactUser = WebServiceBea.GetUserAddress(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
  confmodel.cart = cart;
  confmodel.user = contactUser;
  return PartialView(confmodel);
}
```

Here is my View

```
@model MvcBeaWeb.Models.ConfirmationModel
<div class="pmc-page-container" id="" style="position: relative; width: 85%; ">
  <!-- Address Div -->
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "OrderSummary", new { mod = Model }, FormMethod.Get, null))
  { 
    <div class="address" style="overflow: hidden;">
      <div style="width: 100%; float: left; line-height: 15px; margin: 5px 0px;" class="radio-line">
        @foreach (var item in Model.user.AddressContact)
        {
          <div>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.user.AddressContact, new { id = "item" + item.Id })
            @Html.Label(item.NameCompany, item.NameCompany)
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    </div>      
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  }
</div>
```

---

The problem is : I've got an radiobutton which should present all the address from the List of an user. But when I click the submit button I've got no selection (I cannot get the selected address) and actually the ConfirmationModel in my **OrderSummary Controller** is empty (my form is posting to this controller)- like the binding is not working at all

```
public class OrderSummaryController : Controller
{
  [Authorize]
  public ActionResult Index(ConfirmationModel mod)
```

Comment: Try having a property, like `AddressSelectIndex` and bind your RadioButton's to that with simple numeric values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have numerous issue with your code. Firstly, a radio button group posts back a single value but your trying to bind to a complex object. Your view indicates your creating a form for selecting the contact so create a view model that represents what you want to display and edit

View model

```
public class ContactVM
{
  public int SelectedContact { get; set; }
  public List<Contact> ContactList { get; set; }
  // Add any other properties that you want to display/edit
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ConfirmationOrder()
{
  ContactVM model= new ContactVM();
  // populate the collection of contacts (and set the value of SelectedContact if you want a default item selected)
  return View(model);
}

public ActionResult ConfirmationOrder(ContactVM model)
{
  // model.SelectedContact now contains the ID of the selected contact
}
```

View

```
@model ContactVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @foreach (var contact in Model.Contacts)
  {
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedContact, contact.ID, new { id = contact.Id })
    <label for="@contact.Id>@contact.NameCompany</label>
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Note the `for` attribute in the `label` tag to associate the text with the button.

Next you have stated your want a POST but use `FormMethod.Get` in `BeginForm`, but worse, you attempt to pass the model as route parameters. In the case of a simple model with just a few value type properties this will work, however you have a model with complex properties and collections. Apart from the ugly query string this would create, and the fact that it would soon exceed the query string limit (throwing an exception), it just wont work. Inspect the html in the `form` tag. You will see things like `user=MvcBeaWeb.Models.User"` so when you submit the model binder tries to set your `user` property to the string `"MvcBeaWeb.Models.User"` which fails (you can assign a string to a complex object) and the `user` property is reset to `null`. Its unclear why your trying to do this (why would you degrade performance by sending your whole model to the client, then post it all back unchanged?).

You should post back your view model to a POST method, save the data, then redirect to your `Index()` method (but you have not posted your `ConfirmationModel` or the main view so its a little hard to be more specific).